# How do I parameterize table & column in a Postgres-custom-function, selecting PK if value exists, otherwise insert it and return PK anyways?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql

Trying to do what I specified in the title, I already got the upsert-functionalities working, however when I try to parameterize it, I'm just out of my depth and can't debug it.

My query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom_upsert(target_value_input text, 
                                         target_table_input text,
                                         target_column_input text,
                                         OUT pk_output int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   LOOP
      execute 'SELECT id '
      ' FROM '  || target_table_input || 
      ' WHERE ' || target_column_input || ' =  ' || target_value_input ||
      ' INTO pk_output';

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
      
      execute 'INSERT  INTO ' || target_table_input || 'AS o ( ' || target_column_input || ' )'
      ' VALUES ( ' || target_value_input || ' ) '
      ' ON CONFLICT ( ' || target_column_input || ' ) DO NOTHING '
      ' RETURNING o.id'
      ' INTO pk_output';

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

now when I try to use the function, I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 1: ...module WHERE artifact_id =  artifact_id_example_1 INTO pk_ou...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  SELECT id  FROM maven_module WHERE artifact_id =  artifact_id_example_1 INTO pk_output
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function custom_upsert(text,text,text) line 4 at EXECUTE
```

What puzzles me about this is the fact that this syntax works fine in an unparameterized version:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=765389a746d3a392bc646fbedb7ed3b3

My attempts at parameterization:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1bffab45d8a9587342a7c3253ea35fc8

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=de6ba235aa21dae33b922f8fddac3b63

Thank you very much in advance, first time posting so if there's anything I should do differently when asking a question, I'm happy about feedback

edit: this is my function call:

```
-- should return pk of existing artifact_id
SELECT custom_upsert('artifact_id_example_1', 'maven_module', 'artifact_id');  

-- should return pk of new artifact_id
SELECT custom_upsert('artifact_id_example_2', 'maven_module', 'artifact_id');
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be an issue in this example too then?:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=765389a746d3a392bc646fbedb7ed3b3

Comment: Your second statement `execute 'INSERT  INTO ' || target_column_input || ...` sounds strange : `target_column_input` should be the name of a table, is it ?

Comment: Oh, now I realized what you were trying to say, of course you're right, that was an oversight! I still get the same error though

Comment: In your SELECT statement, the INTO clause must be right after the SELECT clause and before the FROM clause : `SELECT id INTO pk_output FROM ...`

Comment: @aufkeinsten is this what you're looking for? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=92b16f08d77df01316abdd01df21e7bd

Comment: Should this not already be an issue in the unparameterized version which works just fine?

Comment: @JimJones tyvm, that looks perfect to me, this has been bugging me for quite a while now!

Comment: @aufkeinsten could you also validate this one here? So that I can post an answer for you to accept: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d299b41991b27d840fbac2f41791182e

Comment: yep, that looks right to me, will happily accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not concatenate strings like that. The function [`format()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-format/) makes your life much easier (safer), e.g.

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %1$I AS o (%2$I) 
                VALUES (%3$L) ON CONFLICT (%2$I) DO NOTHING RETURNING o.id',
                target_table_input,
                target_column_input,
                target_value_input) INTO pk_output;
```

- `%I` will wrap the identifiers with double quote, which is handy when tables or columns are case sensitive of contain special characters.
- `%L` will wrap the literals with single quotes
- `1$`, `2$` and `3$` are the variables positions provided in the `format()` call, which is quite handy if one variable is used more than once.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d299b41991b27d840fbac2f41791182e)

Comment: ty again not only for the solution but also for the great explanation, helped me out a ton